# Importing svgs with TypeScript + Webpack

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I have a pretty simple Webpack + TypeScript setup and am trying to import svgs. I'm using `svg-sprite-loader` and it works well if I `require()` my svgs like the following:

```
require('./assets/alert.svg')
```

--

However, I'd prefer to use the following:

```
import alert from './assets/alert.svg'
```

With that, I get the following error:

```
TS2307: Cannot find module './assets/alert.svg'.
```

I have a `custom.d.ts` file in my project root (after reading this: https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/#importing-other-assets). It looks like this:

```
declare module '*.svg' {
  const content: any;
  export default content;
}
```

My `tsconfig` looks like:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "sourceMap": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

And finally, my webpack set up includes:

```
 module: {
   rules: [
       {
           test: /\.ts$/,
           use: `awesome-typescript-loader`
       },
       {
           test: /\.html$/,
           loader: 'html-loader'
       },
       {
           test: /\.svg$/,
           loader: 'svg-sprite-loader'
       }
   ]
 }
```

I'm trying to understand how that `custom.d.ts` file comes into play. Is there something I need to add in my `tsconfig`?

Also, for versions, I'm using:

- Webpack @ 2.5.0
- TypeScript @ 2.4.0
- svg-sprite-loader @ 3.6.2
- awesome-typescript-loader @ 3.1.2

Comment: Is there anything else in your `custom.d.ts`?

Comment: Nope, just that!

Comment: Seems like this setup should work. What compile or webpack error do you get after adding `custom.d.ts`?

Comment: `TS2307: Cannot find module './assets/alert.svg'` (from the file that has the import statement)

Comment: Do you get that if you run `tsc` directly or only through webpack?

Comment: I get that error in both scenarios (running `tsc` and through webpack)

Comment: I have an almost identical setup and it works, I didn't need to add anything to get the `*.svg` definition to be visible to the rest of the code... one difference is that I define a `rootDir` in tsconfig

Comment: That's an interesting thought. My tsconfig is actually not in the project root. My `awesome-typescript-loader` specifies its location, but it isn't in the same directory as my `custom.d.ts` - I tried adding a `rootDir` and had the same behavior, but I'm wondering if there's something to that...

Answer (score 3):

Try adding

```
"files": [ 
  "custom.d.ts" 
]
```

to your tsconfig.json

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a [typeRoot](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types) in your tsconfig.json pointing to the location of custom.d.ts.

Comment: Sure, but I don't want this behavior:
"This config file will include all packages under ./typings, and no packages from ./node_modules/@types"

Is there away to specify a `typeRoot` to include just this file without the behavior mentioned above?